# discord.js mysql cooldown

Tags: javascript, mysql

Как сделать кулл даун?
пример:
Пользователь пишет daily
данные записываются в дб и создается кулдаун например на 12 часов.
если он пишет команду например через 1 час ему должно выдать что ввести эту команду можно будет снова 11.02.2020 в 22:17

Comment: Навесить триггер на таблицу, который проверит, что срок вышел, и если нет - сгенерит ошибку с нужным сообщением.

Answer (score 0):

Для вашего вопроса существует множество вариантов реализации и разные варианты будут иметь разную сложность проработки.

Если говорить абстрактно, вам необходимо выполнить следующие **шаги** для реализации задачи:

1. Каждая ваша команда должна вызываться из **отдельного** файла ( Например через [Command Helper](https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/))
2. Каждой команде необходимо присвоить некий **ID**, для идентификации ее в БД.
3. Следующим шагом будет определение структуры вашей базы данных: Вы можете задать Cooldown статично, например как один из параметров `command Handler`, или же сделать соответствующую таблицу в БД и создать логику настройки данного Cooldown через комманду. Первый вариант более простой для для начальной реализации.
4. Создаете Базу данных, в которой вы будуте хранить ваши cooldown с примерно таким набором полей `(guild_id, user_id, command_id, end)` Где:

> `guild_id` - ID сервера, `user_id` - ID пользователя, `command_id` - ID комманды, `end` - время в формате `timestamp` после которого можно использовать комманду снова.

6. При использование команды делаете селект по указанным параметрам, если значение БД не найдены, комманду можно использовать и в БД необходимо сделать Insert с указанными выше параметрами.
7. Если какой-то результат найден, сравниваем даты, в случае если `new Date().getTime()` меньше `end`, выводим ошибку, если больше - разрешаем использование команды и устанавливаем новый cooldown  (в поле `end` значение `new Date().getTime()` + cooldown в секундах)